# Continuously differentiable function and relations with the derivative.

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Let $f$ be a function in $\mathbb{R}$ has continuous derivative $f^\prime$ and $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}| f^\prime(x)=1\}$ is not empty.

a)Its true that $f(x)=x+c$ in all $\mathbb{R}$?

b)And if $A$ is open, Its true that $f(x)=x+c$ in all $\mathbb{R}$?

c)Its true that $f(x)=x+c$ in all $x\in A$?

Notice that $f^\prime$ is a continuous function and $A$ is closed. If $A$ is open then $f^\prime(x)=1$ for all $x\in B(a,r)$, $r>0$. Therefore $f(x)= x+c$ in the ball. Hence $f^\prime$ is continuous and $A$ open, maybe I can control the constante $c$.

Comment: Please separate the question from your attempted answers and explain your thinking a lot more. This is not just a place to get homework answers

Comment: Maybe try to reformulate the question in your own words to grasp what the question asks. Also defining $f^\prime$ piecewise  may be an answer for 2).

Comment: I tried to change something! I think the question is clear... thanks!

Comment: Just because the derivative is constant on $A$ does not mean it is constant everywhere. Look up what a bump function is.

Answer (score 0):

a) False. Take, for instance, $f(x)=x^2$ and $A=\{\frac{1}{2}\}$.

b) False. Take, for instance, $f(x)=x$ for $x<1$, $f(x)=2$ for $x>2$ and $f(x)=\rho(x)$ in $[1,2]$, $\rho$ being a smooth function that conects both intervals (a [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function), any [mollifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier)...).

c) False if $A$ is not open. Take, for instance, $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $A=\{k\pi\ |\ k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. If $A$ is open, then it is true.